# How to group Wordpress posts in years and then months?

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a function with post query and with following structure in output:

```
    2021
      January
        1.Post Title
        2.Post Title
      March
        3.Post Title

    2020
      May
        4.Post Title
```

Here is what I've done so far:

```
global $post;

$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'history',
    'orderby'   => 'date'
) );

$_year_mon = '';
$_has_grp = false;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    $time = strtotime( $post->post_date );
    $year = date( 'Y', $time );
    $mon = date( 'F', $time );
    $year_mon = "$year-$mon";

    if ( $year_mon !== $_year_mon ) {
        // Close previous group, if any.
        if ( $_has_grp ) {
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        $_has_grp = true;

        echo '<div class="year">';
        echo "<span>$year</span>";

        echo '<div class="month">';
        echo "<span>$mon</span>";
    }

    // Display post title.
    if ( $title = get_the_title() ) {
        echo "<div>$title</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div>#{$post->ID}</div>";
    }

    $_year_mon = $year_mon;
}

if ( $_has_grp ) {
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

The problem is that same year with multiple month is not grouped in one element..

Current output:

```
    2021
      January
        1.Post Title
        2.Post Title
    
    2021
      March
        3.Post Title
    
    2020
      May
        4.Post Title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following solution has been fully tested and works seamlessly fine for the default wordpress `post` type. If you want to run it for your custome post type that has its own custom fields then  you may encounter some discrepancies. Therefore, feel free to customize it for your own custom post type as needed.

As we talked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921543/how-to-get-post-data-form-wp-query-array-in-multidimensional-array/), when you use `get_posts` it will return `post objects`. Each `post object` contains the following properties/data:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] =>
    [post_author] =>
    [post_date] => 
    [post_date_gmt] => 
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] =>
    [comment_status] =>
    [ping_status] => 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] =>
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 
    [post_modified_gmt] =>
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 
    [guid] => 
    [menu_order] =>
    [post_type] =>
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] =>
    [filter] =>
)
```

For example if you need, `title`, `content`, `author`, `exerpt` of the post, then you could create a multi-dimensional array and use `array_push` function to create your custom array like so:

```php
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'history', // Since 'history' is a custom post type, I tested it on 'post'
//'post_type' => 'post'
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby'   => 'date'
));

// You could see the number of posts for your query
echo "Number of posts found: ". count($posts) . "<br>";

$your_custom_array_yearly = array();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  $time = strtotime($post->post_date);
  $year = date('Y', $time);
  $mon = date('F', $time);

  if (!($your_custom_array_yearly[$year][$mon])) {
    $your_custom_array_yearly[$year][$mon] = array();
    array_push(
      $your_custom_array_yearly[$year][$mon],
      [
        'title'   => $post->post_title,
        'excerpt' => $post->post_excerpt,
        'author'  => $post->post_author,
        'content' => $post->post_content,
      ]
    );
  } else {
    array_push(
      $your_custom_array_yearly[$year][$mon],
      [
        'title'   => $post->post_title,
        'excerpt' => $post->post_excerpt,
        'author'  => $post->post_author,
        'content' => $post->post_content,
      ]
    );
  };
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

For debugging/investigating the array, you could use this:

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_custom_array_yearly);
echo "</pre>";
```

Now that you have your own custom array, then you could loop through it and output your data:

```php
foreach ((array)$your_custom_array_yearly as $yearly => $yvalue) {
  echo $yearly . ": <br>";
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($yvalue as $monthly => $mvalue) {
    echo "<li>" . $monthly . ": </li><ul>";
    foreach ($mvalue as $monthly_k => $monthly_v) {
      foreach ($monthly_v as $post_title_k => $post_title_v) {
        echo "<li>" . $post_title_k . ": " . $post_title_v . "</li></ul>";
      }
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

The above code will output the following result:

```
2021:
  January:
    1.Title: Post Title
    1.Excerpt: Post excerpt
    1.Author: Post author
    1.Content: Post content
    2.Title: Post Title
    2.Excerpt: Post excerpt
    2.Author: Post author
    2.Content: Post content
  March:
    3.Title: Post Title
    3.Excerpt: Post excerpt
    3.Author: Post author
    3.Content: Post content

2020:
  May:
    4.Title: Post Title
    4.Excerpt: Post excerpt
    4.Author: Post author
    4.Content: Post content
```

Comment: Really appreciate for your explanations! A bit confused with 4th level foreach, in my implementation i got: `foreach ($month_value as $monthly_k => $monthly_v) { $output_inner .= '<div class="visible">'; foreach ($monthly_v as $post_title_k => $post_title_v) { $output_inner .= '<div><h3>'. $post_title_k .'</h3>'. $post_title_v .'</div>'; } $output_inner .= '</div>'; } }`  Which outputs: `<div class="visible"><div><h3>title</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [cloned]</div><div><h3>content</h3><!-- content --></div></div>` Unwanted titles in h3 tags, probably something wrong with wrapping.

Comment: Well, i tested it yesterday on one of my blogs, and it works seamlessly fine! The only difference was i used `'post_type' => 'post'` instead of `'post_type' => 'history'` which is a custom post type that i believe you've come up with, which brings us to its html structure! The html structure that you see on your end would come out of your `title`, `excerpt`, `content` and the `author` of your custom post type `history`.  By default, my foreach loop does not output `h3`s or `div`s etc. My foreach only has a simple `ul` and `li` tags, any extra html tag/structure you see, comes from your end.

Comment: I see.. btw, managed to get values only by using `$monthly_v[$post_title_v]` but when wrapping in tag e.g. `$output_inner .= '<h3>' . $monthly_v[$post_title_v] . '</h3>';` for example, tag appears outside the string in output. I'll investigate it more deeply, thx!!!

Comment: To debug/investigate the code, you could create a few "dummy" history posts WITHOUT any html tag in their `content`, `title`, `excerpt`. Then run the code and see the results for the simple dummy data you just created for debugging purposes, then you'll understand what's going on. Like i said it works **OK** on the default wordpress `post`. Tested it yesterday before i sent it to you.

Comment: Figured it out! That one works in my case: `foreach ($month_value as $monthly_k => $monthly_v) { $output_inner .= '<div class="visible">'; $output_inner .= '<h3>'; foreach ($monthly_v as $content_key => $content_value) { $output_inner .= $content_value; $output_inner .= '</h3>'; } $output_inner .= '</div>'; }` Tried to buy you a coffee, but canceled my PayPal subscription, do you have alternative wallet? =)

Comment: And how I can get repeated years? Same as in `Current output` in my question, but with your implementation, e.g repeated `$yearly` value in each month

Comment: Not sure that i understood your question. Would you please explain more? Or if there is no room here to ask, you could go ahead and open up a new question and i'll try to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, just wanted to print year for each post in output. Figured it out, printed `$yearly` in foreach `$mvalue`  loop =)

Answer (score 1):

Create an multidimensional array like this way and print it. You might get appropriate result.

```
$master = [];

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    $time = strtotime( $post->post_date );
    $year = date( 'Y', $time );
    $mon = date( 'F', $time );
    
    $master[$year][$mon][] = $post;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($master);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Nice solution! Trying to iterate array this way: `foreach ($master as $masterkey => $mastervalue) { echo "<p>"; echo "masterkey: ".  $masterkey . "<br>"; foreach($mastervalue as $key => $value) { echo "key: " . $key . "<br>"; echo "value: " . $value . "<br>"; } echo "</p>"; }` How I can get post data form `$value` array?

Comment: Found a solution: `$value['content'] = get_the_content()`

Comment: You will get whole post object in $value so setup post data again in loop and you can access built in function like get_permalink(), get_title(), get_the_content() etc