# How to get post data form WP_Query array in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I get `$value` array values from `object(WP_Query)`?

post_content, ID, pagename, category etc.

**Here is my code:**

```php
    global $post;
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'history',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
    );
    
    $master = [];
        
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if ($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                
        while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
                
            $post_query->the_post();
            
            /* Get Post Date */
            $year = get_the_date( 'Y' );
            $mon = get_the_date( 'M' );
                
            $master[$year][$mon][] = $post_query;
            
        }
        
        foreach ($master as $masterkey => $mastervalue) {
            echo "<p>";

            echo "masterkey: ".  $masterkey . "<br>";

            foreach($mastervalue as $key => $value) {
                echo "key: " . $key . "<br>";
                echo "value: " . $value . "<br>";
                                        
            }
            
            echo "</p>";
        }
        
    }

wp_reset_postdata();
```

**var_dump for `$value` array:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Query)#2459 (51) { ["query"]=> array(2) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "history" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" } ["query_vars"]=> array(63) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "history" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["lazy_load_term_meta"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(10) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#2465 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_table"]=> string(11) "pkctU_posts" ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" } ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#2452 (9) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL ["meta_table"]=> NULL ["meta_id_column"]=> NULL ["primary_table"]=> NULL ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["clauses":protected]=> array(0) { } ["has_or_relation":protected]=> bool(false) } ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["request"]=> string(295) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pkctU_posts.ID FROM pkctU_posts WHERE 1=1 AND pkctU_posts.post_type = 'history' AND (pkctU_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR pkctU_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR pkctU_posts.post_status = 'dp-rewrite-republish') ORDER BY pkctU_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10" ["posts"]=> array(8) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#2458 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(3786) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-24 18:34:38" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-24 15:34:38" ["post_content"]=> string(1937) "
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this question is related to [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68910349/how-to-group-wordpress-posts-in-years-and-then-months), and you need the title of each post in this format `Year > Months > Title of each post`, then you could use the following code:

```php
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'history',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby'   => 'date'
));

$master = [];

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);

  $time = strtotime($post->post_date);
  $year = date('Y', $time);
  $mon = date('F', $time);

  $master[$year][$mon][] = $post->post_title;
}

wp_reset_postdata();


foreach ((array)$master as $yearly => $yvalue) {
  echo $yearly . ": <br>";
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($yvalue as $monthly => $mvalue) {
    echo "<li>" . $monthly . ": </li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($mvalue as $post_title_k => $post_title_v) {
      echo "<li>" . $post_title_v . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Notice that i used `post_title` from the `post object`. Which will return the following output:

```
2021:
  January:
    1.Post Title
    2.Post Title
  March:
    3.Post Title

2020:
  May:
    4.Post Title
```

When you use `get_posts` it will return `post objects`. Each object includes the followings:

```php
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] =>
    [post_author] =>
    [post_date] => 
    [post_date_gmt] => 
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] =>
    [comment_status] =>
    [ping_status] => 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] =>
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 
    [post_modified_gmt] =>
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 
    [guid] => 
    [menu_order] =>
    [post_type] =>
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] =>
    [filter] =>
)
```

In the code above i accessed `$post->post_title` in this line `$master[$year][$mon][] = $post->post_title`.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. And that was perfect timing, I've placed `wp_reset_postdata();` in the wrong place and got duplicates in array. And how I can get `[post_content]` in foreach? Should I assign another dimension `$master[$year][$mon][][]` or there is another way?

Comment: You could access `the post content` by using this `$post->post_content`. For your second question, you could use `array_push` to include `the post content` and any property/data from `post object` in an array. If you're not sure how to do it, then let me know, i'll include the proper code in your original question.

Comment: That will be great, I'm not sure how array_push works... As I can understand there is a way to store both post_content and title as properties of object and assign it to `$master[$year][$mon][]`?

Comment: Sure. Just posted my answer to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68927955/15040627).

Answer (score 1):

Try to ensure `$master` is a multi-dimensional array before assigning values like `$master[$year][$mon][] = $post_query;`

```
while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
                
    $post_query->the_post();
            
    /* Get Post Date */
    $year = get_the_date( 'Y' );
    $mon = get_the_date( 'M' );
    
    if (!is_array($master[$year]) {
        $master[$year] = [];
    }
    if (!is_array($master[$year][$mon]) {
        $master[$year][$mon] = [];
    }
    $master[$year][$mon][] = $post_query;
            
}
```

Comment: Oh, you missed closing bracket in if statement, but yes that helped